# checkbox and label not inline CSS Magento form

Tags: css, magento

[This is what is showing what ever css style I put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF7BA.png)

[I really want to have this please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omf31.png)

```
<li><div class="wide checkbox-inline">
<label class="required" for="options[3]">Delivery Day  <em>*</em> </label>
<div class="input-box">
<ul class="options-list"><li><input type="checkbox" name="options[3][]" id="options_3_text_Sunday" class="checkbox" title="Sunday" value="Sunday"><label for="options_3_text_Sunday"> Sunday</label></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="options[3][]" id="options_3_text_Monday" class="checkbox" title="Monday" value="Monday"><label for="options_3_text_Monday"> Monday</label></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="options[3][]" id="options_3_text_Tuesday" class="checkbox" title="Tuesday" value="Tuesday"><label for="options_3_text_Tuesday"> Tuesday</label></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="options[3][]" id="options_3_text_Wednesday" class="checkbox" title="Wednesday" value="Wednesday"><label for="options_3_text_Wednesday"> Wednesday</label></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="options[3][]" id="options_3_text_Thursday" class="checkbox" title="Thursday" value="Thursday"><label for="options_3_text_Thursday"> Thursday</label></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="options[3][]" id="options_3_text_Friday" class="checkbox" title="Friday" value="Friday"><label for="options_3_text_Friday"> Friday</label></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="options[3][]" id="options_3_text_Saturday" class="checkbox validate-one-required-by-name" title="Saturday" value="Saturday"><label for="options_3_text_Saturday"> Saturday</label></li></ul>        </div>
 </div></li>

.checkboxes label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.checkboxes input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.checkboxes label span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: we cant help you if you don't show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you added the code, i took a closer look. Seems the problem is caused by use of the UL (unordered list). The list sums up all the list-items (LI's), which normally start on a new rule for every item.
Normally this is what you want by adding a list, but in this case you don't want to sum up the checkboxes in a list.

To solve the problem the fast way, you can use this styling:

```
.options-list li{
  display: inline;
}
```

The better way is to leave out the < li >- and < ul >-tags  in this case. 
Check this out for the working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/crix/o1du23b3/

Hope this helps!

Comment: .checkboxes label {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}
.checkboxes input {
    display: inline;
}
.checkboxes label span {
    display: inline;
}  --this is not working

Comment: Thank you very much you made my day! got it working by editing the code you gave .options-list li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

Comment: No problem. Happy to help you :-)